# how to substring 5 character of every tag p in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, substring

I have an array of `p` tags and I want to `substring(0,5)` for every `p` tag in the array and replace the previous ones. But my code isn't working correctly.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="test1">
     <p class="cls">1.Im try to use the click function </p>
     <p class="cls">2.Im try to use the click function </p>
     <p class="cls">3.Im try to use the click function </p>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.cls').each(function () {
         var iTotalWords = $(this).text().split(' ');
         for (i = 0 ; i < iTotalWords.length; i++) {
             var result = iTotalWords.substring(0, 50);
             $(".cls").html(result);​
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: Why do you split the text ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several problems.

You shouldn't use generic selector. You have to use current element which is `this`.

You don't need a loop and split as you get complete text and just substring it.

substring(0, 50) run you into issues as there are no 50 characters in your String. You mean `0,5` right ?

---

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cls').each(function () {
        var iTotalWords = $(this).text();        
        var result = iTotalWords.substr(0, 5);
        $(this).html(result); });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">
    <p class="cls">1.Im try to use the click function </p>
    <p class="cls">2.Im try to use the click function </p>
    <p class="cls">3.Im try to use the click function </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure if you wish to get 5 characters or 5 words, so I've included both.

Get the `.cls` elements, iterate using `.each()`, and for each paragraph get the text, and substring or slice to get what you want.

```js
/** five characters **/
$('.test1 .cls').each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0, 5));
});

/** five words **/
$('.test2 .cls').each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text().split(' ').slice(0, 5).join(' '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">
  <p class="cls">1.Im try to use the click function </p>
  <p class="cls">2.Im try to use the click function </p>
  <p class="cls">3.Im try to use the click function </p>
</div>

<div class="test2">
  <p class="cls">1.Im try to use the click function </p>
  <p class="cls">2.Im try to use the click function </p>
  <p class="cls">3.Im try to use the click function </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

sweet and simple

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cls').each(function () {
            console.log("with substr(start,end) ::"+$(this).text().substr(0,4));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you chose to do so just with pure JS you may simply do as follows;

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div.test1 > p')
        .forEach(p => p.textContent = p.textContent.substr(0,5));
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <p class="cls">1.Im try to use the click function </p>
  <p class="cls">2.Im try to use the click function </p>
  <p class="cls">3.Im try to use the click function </p>
</div>
```